# How to create a service principal without app, and create an app without service principal in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, service-principal

Recently I watched a course on Pluralsight.com, *Getting Started with Azure Active Directory for Developers*. In the section, `Service Principals`->`Apps and Service Principals`, the author said that we can create a service principal **without** app, and it's also possible to create an app **without** service principal. But he didn't show how to do so, and I cannot find out online how to do so either. So how can we do so? And can we do so from the Azure Portal?

Comment: Hi mate @RahulKumarShaw-MT, thanks for you answer. But i'm not convinced by this statement `It is not possible to create a service principle without creating an application.` yet, so still waiting ...

Answer (score 4):

***Yes it is possible to create an azure ad app without creating a service principle(using powershell only) . Through portal if you will create it will create service princple along with app.
You can view the newly created app in the App registrations blade, under All applications in the Azure portal***

**Powershell cmdlet.**

```
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "MTS Demo App"
```

[image]
[image]

***It is not possible to create a service principle without creating an application.*** **Service Principle will create an azure active directory as an application**

```
# Create a service principal for a resource group using a preferred name and role
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name myServicePrincipalName \
                         --role reader \
                         --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID/resourceGroups/myResourceGroupName
```

**Note : For creating Service Principle you need to admin role at the subscription level and Adminsitator role at Azure Active Directory Level.**

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli#code-try-0***

Comment: You can also watch this youtube video as well for the same : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-F9yzj4Kjeo